# Need to check array of imageviews for backgroundresource, clickable or imageresource (Android)

Tags: android, if-statement

I'm creating a memory app (you know where you have to select 2 images and match them). I'm looking for a way to check when there are no images left so I can show a message.

I have this code to check if the images match. I'm working with 2 arrays, 1 holds the imageviews and their position in the grid (playfield) and one holds the reference for which image is on that imageview (cards).

```
    private void checkCards() {
    if (cards[value1] == cards[value2]) {
        playfield[value1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_red);
        playfield[value2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_red);
        playfield[value1].setClickable(false);
        playfield[value2].setClickable(false);
        score++;
    } else {
        playfield[value1].setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
        playfield[value2].setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
    }
    value1 = -1;
    value2 = -1;
}
```

I need to check on one of these conditions:

- There are no more imageviews without a red border
- There are no more imageviews that are clickable
- There are no more imageviews with the R.drawable.back imageresource

However I'm not sure on how to do this? Do any of you have an idea or even a better method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For #2, you could iterate through the array and check if `playfield[i].isClickable()`

Comment: That would be a possibility, however you'd have to run through the collection again. With that in mind I think @moxi hit the spot, clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep a counter of each one, I can think on more complicated solutions, but a pretty straightforward one will be to have a counter and increase that counter when you're assigning the clickables, the borders, etc... e.g:

```
private void checkCards() {
    if (cards[value1] == cards[value2]) {
        playfield[value1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_red);
        playfield[value2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_red);
        playfield[value1].setClickable(false);
        playfield[value2].setClickable(false);
        mCounterClickables--; // one less clickable
        mRedDrawables++; // one more Red Drawable
        mBlackDrawables--;
        score++;
    } else {
        playfield[value1].setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
        playfield[value2].setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
        mBlackDrawables++; //
    }
    value1 = -1;
    value2 = -1;
    }
```

Then to validate that you're done:

```
public boolean imDone() {
        return mBlackDrawables == 0 && mCounterClickables== 0 
          && mRedDrawables == playfield.length;
    }
```

Does it makes sense?

In this way you don't have to iterate over and over again, you will always have track of what the user has done.

Btw. The initial state of your variables should be something like this:

```
int mBlackDrawables = 0, mCounterClickables = playfield.length, mRedDrawables = 0;
```

Comment: Having an extra counter makes sense, I feel so stupid for trying to find a difficult method when the solution is so simple. Thanks for the swift answer.